# Dockerized Node JS project getting: "command failed signal SIGTERM" error

Tags: node.js, docker, express, npm, kubernetes

I had a express application and I used this application in my Kubernetes cluster.

This application is auth service for my micro service architecture study.

I use Skaffold dev command for applying Kubernetes for this app.

My Dockerfile is like that:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And I run it with "Scaffold dev" command

And I getting error like that:

```
...
...    
Deployments stabilized in 3.752 seconds
Watching for changes...
[auth] npm notice 
[auth] npm notice New patch version of npm available! 7.5.1 -> 7.5.4
[auth] npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v7.5.4>
[auth] npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@7.5.4` to update!
[auth] npm notice 
[auth] npm ERR! path /app
[auth] npm ERR! command failed
[auth] npm ERR! signal SIGTERM
[auth] npm ERR! command sh -c node server.js
[auth] 
[auth] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[auth] npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-02-19T16_46_28_956Z-debug.log
```

And my package.json file :

```
    {
  "name": "authservice",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Auth Service",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "auth",
    "user"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-rate-limit": "^5.2.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "5.10.19",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  }
}
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Please add `package.json` to your question

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're either incorrectly specifying your script in the `package.json` or your script is not `server.js`.

A minimal repro of your question works:

Using the Node.JS Getting Started guide's example with one minor tweak:
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/

> **NOTE** Change `const hostname = '127.0.0.1';` to `const hostname = '0.0.0.0';` This is necessary to access the containerized app from the host.

Adding a package.json because you have one and to show `npm start`:

`package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "66281738",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node app.js"
    }
}
```

> **NOTE** I believe `npm start` defaults to `"start": "node server.js"`

Using your `Dockerfile` and:

```sh
QUESTION="66281738"
docker build --tag=${QUESTION} --file=./Dockerfile .
docker run --interactive --tty --publish=7777:3000 ${QUESTION}
```

Yields:

```
> 66281738@0.0.1 start
> node app.js

Server running at http://0.0.0.0:3000/
```

> **NOTE** `docker run` binds the container's `:3000` port to the host's `:7777` just to show these need not be the same.

Then:

```sh
curl --request GET http://localhost:3000/
```

Yields:

```
Hello World
```

Comment: Unable to understand what you're stating. Very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue. Please check the liveliness probe and readiness probe path.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To clarify this a bit for future readers, take a look at your kubernetes manifest. You'll see livelinessProbe, readinessProbe, and/or startupProbe -- these should return valid responses, e.g. 200 status code if an API call. More info here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/